# fire function when custom filter ended filtering ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two selects and options of select#campaign are filtered(act is  custom filter) by select#activeinactive ngModel.

I need to fire js function(I use [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) and just need to call $('#campaign').selectpicker('refresh')) when filtering is finished and #campaign DOM(options) is constructed.

How to do that? I tried $scope.watch('activeinactive',fn) but it(above mentioned selectpicker('refresh')) is fired when select#campaign DOM is not yet ready. thanx

```
<select id="activeinactive" name="activeinactive" ng-model="activeinactive" multiple>
   <option value="Enabled">Active</option>
   <option value="Disabled">Inactive</option>
</select>
<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in $ctrl.items | act:activeinactive track by item.value"
        name="campaign[]" ng-model="campaign" id="campaign" multiple>
</select>
```

Comment: This feels like an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).   What are you *actually trying to accomplish*?  "fire a function when filtering is finished" doesn't explain the problem you are trying to solve, it describes a potential solution that you are trying, that isn't in the angular paradigm.

Comment: Exactly.. what u r trying to do is unclear.. please explain why you want to refresh your list after it is filtered if you do that then what is sense of filtering your list.